# Не могу прочитать с консоли visual studio 2019 кириллицу

Tags: visual-studio, консоль, кодировка, кириллица

```
int main() {
    char faculty[20];
    ss=setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    f = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    printf("Введите название факультета \n");
    scanf("%s", faculty);
    fgets(faculty, 19, f);  
    .......................
```

Менял кодировки в консоли, параметры setlocale.
Вывод корректный, но scanf с консоли не берёт кириллицу
Возвращает (кажется) utf-16